# Subsection numbering not working

Tags: sectioning

I have a problem that all the subsections numbers in my report.
How can I solve this problem please?
I search for a solution and I try it but it also not working. this is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand\thesection{\color{myblue}\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\color{myorange}\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\subsection{\bf\color{myorange}Overview}
\subsection{\bf\color{myorange}{Declarative Development:}}
\subsection{\bf\color{myorange}{Programmatic Development:}}
```

these 3 subsections shows :

```
1.1 Overview
1.1 Declarative Development
1.1 Programmatic Development
```

Anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the problem? You didn't explain it.

Comment: my problem is that the subsection nembering is not working. It's showing the same number for all the subsections

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you have? Using `\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}` I get the correct result.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. And please tell us if your document contains instructions (possibly in the preamble) that modify the properties of `\thesubsection`.

Comment: I edit my post can you check it please

Comment: You probably want `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}`. The color declarations belong elsewhere.

Comment: Yes i change it now and it works!! thankk you but i have another problem the section and the subsection have the same numbering like this example:
1.1 Section
1.1 subsection A
1.2 subsection B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, it is very simple with `titlesec` (as you don't define myblue and my orange in your post, I had to define them myself):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{myorange}{DarkOrange}
\colorlet{myblue}{CadetBlue}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\color{myblue}\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{myorange}\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{section}{4}

\section{First section}
\subsection{Overview}
\subsection{Declarative Development:}
\subsection{Programmatic Development:}

\end{document}
```

[image]